# Creating model method to get data from another model

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have the following tables :

```
Locations:
id
name

areas:
id
name

buildings:
id
name

Reports:
id
content
FK | building_id
```

How can i write a relationship method in App\Report Model file that allow me to show the report (location) <- from \App\Location Model.

I tried with this, in Report model :

```
public function location()
    {
        return Location::whereHas('areas', function($q){
            $q->whereHas('observations',function ($q){
                $q->where('observations.id',$this->id);
            });
        })->get();
    }
```

But it returned an error :

ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Call to undefined method App\Location::whereHas() (View:

Comment: Based on your **very limited** detail, there appears to be no relationship between `locations`, `areas`, nor `buildings`. Only `reports` and `buildings` are related based on your database schema. Can you update your question with the relevant information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Location model should extends Eloquent

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Location extends Model
{
    ...
```

Also it's better to use Laravel relationships for that. You will end up with a code like this

```
public function location()
{
    return $this->building->area->location;
}
```

You will need something like this

```
class Report extends Model
{
    public function location()
    {
        return $this->building->area->location;
    }

    public function building()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\Building::class);
    }
}

class Building extends Model
{
    public function area()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\Area::class);
    }
}

class Area extends Model
{
    public function location()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\Location::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've the exact methods already created on the Model files , i had just  added
 public function location()
    {
        return $this->building->area->location;
    }

Error showing when calling this method in view file ==> {{$o->location->name}}, ErrorException (E_ERROR)
App\Observation::location must return a relationship instance. (View:

Comment: That method is not a Laravel relation since you're not using `belongsTo`, or `hasMany` or other relation stuff, so you can't use it like `$this->location->name`. You need to call the method with parenthesis `$this->location()->name`